# java parsing datetimes incorrectly and assuming local timezone

Tags: java, web-services, datetime, timezone

I have a java web service that I am passing datetimes to, and the server appears to be interpreting the datetimes incorrectly and responding with times set to whatever the timezone is of the local machine running the service.

If I pass the following datetime to a service running on the web,

`startDate: "2014-06-11T05:00:00.000Z"`

Then the datetime returned is

`startDate: "Wed Jun 11 00:00:00 UTC 2014"`

However if I instead post the same date to a local instance of the service, the returned datetime is in my timezone (CDT)

`startDate: "Wed Jun 11 00:00:00 CDT 2014"`

I found that the result is also midnight regardless of what hour value I pass in. On the server side, my code to receive and parse the datetime from the request is

`dateDateFormat.parse("2014-06-11T5:00:00.000Z")`

which evaluates to

`Wed Jun 11 00:00:00 CDT 2014`

How do I correctly receive and parse ISOStrings to Date objects and what is the best way to persist timezone between the client and the server?

Comment: What is the value of `dateDateFormat`?

Comment: Not just that - please post *all* the relevant code. How are you returning the data as well? Basically there isn't nearly enough information here at the moment.

Comment: @Danny, evaluation of the given value is `Wed Jun 11 00:00:00 CDT 2014` on my locally running machine, I suspect it may be a different timezone on the web

Comment: What timezone is configured in server and local machine? Maybe the configuation is different.

Comment: @Jens, it is different. My Local machine is CDT and the server is UTC

Answer (score 2):

Call [setTimeZone(TimeZone)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#setTimeZone%28java.util.TimeZone%29) before your "parse".

```
dateDateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
```

Comment: Elliott, it didn't quite work, when I try to parse the value `2014-06-15T05:00:00.000Z`, the evaluation is now `Sat Jun 14 19:00:00 CDT 2014` which should instead be midnight

Comment: You seem to be confused about what a Date contains. Make sure you use `dateDateFormat.format(date);` to display the value.